# XCTest copy file from phone

Tags: swift, xcode, automated-tests, xctest, xcodebuild

Hello I'm writing XCTests in swift. I need some additional test information that does not fit into to the XCResults. I'm currently writing this to a file on the physical device that's being tested. What I would like to do is at the end of all tests copy this file to the attached computer. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to achieve it is using `XCTAttachment`.
Your test can attach any files to test results and they all are available in the test navigator.

It's all described in detail in this article: [Adding Attachments to Tests, Activities, and Issues](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/activities_and_attachments/adding_attachments_to_tests_activities_and_issues).